# Time complexity of a function

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm trying to find out the time complexity (Big-O) of functions and trying to provide appropriate reason.

First function goes:

```
r = 0
# Assignment is constant time. Executed once. O(1)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        for k in range(i,j):
            r += 1
            # Assignment and access are O(1). Executed n^3
```

like this.

I see that this is triple nested loop, so it must be O(n^3).
but I think my reasoning here is very weak. I don't really get what is going
on inside the triple nested loop here

Second function is:

```
i = n
# Assignment is constant time. Executed once. O(1)
while i>0:
    k = 2 + 2
    i = i // 2
    # i is reduced by the equation above per iteration.
    # so the assignment and access which are O(1) is executed
    # log n times ??
```

I found out this algorithm to be O(1). But like the first function, 
I don't see what is going on in the while-loop.

Can someone explain thoroughly about the time complexity of the two
functions? Thanks!

Comment: nested loops are almost always quadratic unless you are doing some constant work, your second example is `log(n)`.

Comment: Thanks. For the second example, are we ignoring the i = n part?

Comment: i = n is just an assignment, after that we are halving  n each iteration like you would using bisection search

Comment: The first loop is O(n^3), not O(n^2).

Comment: This reference might help: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple case, you could [find the number of iterations of the innermost loop as a function of `n` exactly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BSum%5BSum%5B1%2C%7Bk%2Ci%2Cj-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bj%2Ci%2B1%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bi%2C0%2Cn-1%7D%5D):

```
sum_(i=0)^(n-1)(sum_(j=i+1)^(n-1)(sum_(k=i)^(j-1) 1)) = 1/6 n (n^2-1)
```

i.e., **`Θ(n**3)`** time complexity ([see Big Theta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)): it assumes that `r += 1` is O(1) if `r` has `O(log n)` digits ([model has words with `log n` bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_of_computational_complexity)).

The second loop is even simpler: `i //= 2` is `i >>= 1`. `n` has `Θ(log n)` digits and each iteration drops one binary digit (shift right) and therefore the whole loop is **`Θ(log n)`** time complexity if we assume that the `i >> 1` shift of `log(n)` digits is O(1) operation (same model as in the first example).

Comment: I tried to do that WolframAlpha thing by and and failed, could you show the steps?

Comment: there are no steps, click the link and you should see the result.

Comment: @Jasper: I've forgotten how to do it by hand (computers do it too well -- if it weren't for shopping lists; I'd forgotten how to write). Look for something like [How to find the partial sum of a given series?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/124277) to get the exact result (the advantage is that TeX formulae are rendered there). Or if you want to learn from scratch [how to find partial sums](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/partial-sums.html).

Comment: @Jasper: here's [my attempt to do it manually step by step](http://mathb.in/27825?key=ac01f53c497b9bb7f69434d27722d11a4bfa9526). The answer is not the same ;) You could repeat the process and spot where I've made a mistake.

Answer (score -4):

Well first of all, for the first function, the time complexity seems to be closer to O(N log N) because the parameters of each loop decreases each time.

Also, for the second function, the runtime is O(log2 N). Except, say i == n == 2. After one run i is 1. After another i is 0.5. After another i is 0.25. And so on... I assume you would want int(i).

For a rigorous mathematical approach to each function, you can go to https://www.coursera.org/course/algo. It's a great course for this sort of thing. I was sort of sloppy in my calculations.

Comment: `//` in Python does integer division

Comment: How is the second function O(log N)? Shouldn't it be O(1) since constant dominates over logarithmic?

Comment: "constant dominates over logarithmic"? No.